# use pivot_longer and pivot_wider in combination

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe with lots of `NaN`in various columns.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Data1 = c(3,2,1,NaN, NaN, NaN),
  Data2  = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, 3,5,3),
  Data3 = c(NaN, NaN, 7,5,1, NaN)
)
```

I'm trying to get rid of the `NaN` values by using `pivot_longer`, `filter`ing on the `NaN`values and using `pivot_wider` to put the positive numbers back again into their original columns, which, however, fails:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(c("Data1","Data2","Data3")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,
              values_from = value)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  Data1     Data3     Data2    
  <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 <dbl [3]> <dbl [3]> <dbl [3]>
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

What's wrong with the code and how can this output be achieved?

```
  Data1 Data2 Data3
      3     3     7
      2     5     5
      1     3     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't necessarily fail but return a warning since you have more than one value in each cell. If the number of values in each column are going to be the same you can `unnest` the list output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Data'), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = value, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest()

#  Data1 Data2 Data3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3     3     7
#2     2     5     5
#3     1     3     1
```

Answer (score 3):

This particular problem could be neatly solved using `purrr`:

```
map_dfr(df, na.omit)

  Data1 Data2 Data3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     3     7
2     2     5     5
3     1     3     1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Base R:

I prefer `sapply` with `na.omit`:

```
sapply(df, na.omit)
```

Output:

```
  Data1 Data2 Data3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     3     7
2     2     5     5
3     1     3     1
```